# Can you customize search to find all records for all users?

Tags: apex, search

Is there a way to customize search in Salesforce, so that every user can see all records?

It is annoying, that users have to insert all data for a new Contact, just to get the message "Duplicate detected". And in search results you can't see those contacts, because they are not the owner of it.

Is there a way around this, other than having to make a Visualforce Page and an Apex Class to do all of that?

Comment: Changing your OWD settings, sharing settings,... Things not showing up in search are just not shared with you. Maybe have a look at [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/data_security/data_security_records) if you are not familiar with this?

Comment: hi. consider Robin's comment and try to read this documentation. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm

Comment: They should not be shared. They should just see fields like "Name, E-Mail" in search and not have the ability to access the record.

Comment: No way to go around sharing without coding, as you already assumed. You'll need to build a custom search functionality without sharing.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just did a combo of Visualforce + Tabs + Apex + the App "PageBlockTableEnhancerADV" now. Works, too